# call function from static pointer to another class inside a class

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, function-pointers

I have problems understanding the below code. I searched using Google but I could not find an answer.

```cpp
class B
{
    //constructor etc
    //...some stuff
    virtual myinit();
    virtual doStuff();
};


class A : public B
{   
    //constructor etc
    //...some stuff

    static B * Create()
    {
        A* demo = new A;
        demo->myinit();
        demo->doStuff();
        return demo;
    }
};
```

I know that when I create an `A`, a `B` is created too. But why does `Create()` return a pointer to a type `B`?

Is this method called automatically ? Also, why is it `static` in this way? 
i know what is polymorphism and static means..

Comment: Problem is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`why does Create() return a pointer to a type B?`

You can safely convert a pointer of a derived class to a pointer of its base class.

Why the function does this, you will need to ask the person who wrote it.

`Is this method called automatically?`

No.

`why is it static in this way?`

So that you can call the function without an object of the class. If no A's exist yet and Create weren't static, you wouldn't be able to create any A's using the Create function.

Answer (score 0):

The static method means that this method exists per class and not per object - so its bound to the class. The static method Create() is a well known pattern ([Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)).

In this method an object that points to A is created, the methods are called and returned.

Answer (score 0):

These questions touch to basic concepts of C++

1- polymorphism
2- static semantic on non-member variables.

To polymorphism I advise you to read the introduction here ( http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/ )

For static, you have to know that a static member function can be used without instantiating the class.

Comment: Wrong kind of static.